# Need help solving Project Euler problem 200

Tags: language-agnostic

I am trying to formulate an algorithm to solve [Project Euler's Problem 200](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=200).

> We shall define a sqube to be a number
>   of the form, *p<sup>2</sup>q<sup>3</sup>*, where *p* and *q* are
>   distinct primes. For example, 200 =
>   5<sup>2</sup>2<sup>3</sup> or 120072949 = 23<sup>2</sup>61<sup>3</sup>.
>
> The first five squbes are 72, 108,
>   200, 392, and 500.
>
> Interestingly, 200 is also the first
>   number for which you cannot change any
>   single digit to make a prime; we shall
>   call such numbers, prime-proof. The
>   next prime-proof sqube which contains
>   the contiguous sub-string "200" is
>   1992008.
>
> Find the 200th prime-proof sqube
>   containing the contiguous sub-string
>   "200".

Can someone please point me in the right direction to help me solve this problem?

Comment: People here don't take kindly to just doing work for others. If you have a specific piece of code that has an issue other than "make this work", you will find people more inclined to help you out.

Comment: I did my best to turn this in to a question for Freddy's sake.  It an interesting problem despite the really lazy initial question wording.

Comment: Agreed, It is an interesting question, and one that reminded me that Project Euler is still alive, Its been age's from when i last visited,   
Id also think that if anyone does provide a response, PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE do it in psudo code, and leave the implimentation up to the user, at least that way Its not a complete cheat.

Comment: While you're editing, Michael, can you fix the notation? p2q3 should be p^2q^3, etc.

Comment: @Not_Sure...um you don't "check code in" to Project Euler. Frankly, I think that this question isn't great because it's a gimme-the-codez question, but you don't need to worry about Project Euler being corrupted.  My point is that, vote the question down if necessary, but not because of faulty reasoning...that he's going to "check bad code into Project Euler".

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is a great SO question, but this should get you started at least.

Algorithmically, the brute force and ignorance approach to this should be pretty straightforward:

1. Start with set of primes  P
2. Generate "squbes" by looking at all ordered pairs (p1,p2)  with p1,p2 in P
3. Order this list, call the set S  (think: how can you do this while generating them)
4. Test each s in S in turn, looking for substring 200
5. If s contains "200"  test each one-digit modification of s to see if it's prime
6. If none of them are prime, you've found a prime-proof sqube.  Put it in a list, and when you've found the 200th one you're done.

Now the more interesting thing here is to see if you can do something a bit less brute force and ignorance.  First off, is the above even practical (assuming a fast primality test)?  Easy enough to estimate how fast the squbes grow, but not so much with the prime-proof ones, or the ones containing 200.  Can you see any shortcuts?

Have fun!

Comment: I am wondering, is changing the first digit to 0 allowed?