# Help with Project Euler #200?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help solving Project Euler problem 200](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778387/need-help-solving-project-euler-problem-200)

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778387/)

[Project Euler Problem 200.](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=200)

I wrote up a brute force solution in Java that takes several hours to run, and produced the first 500+ sqube numbers, which I thought should be enough. However, none of the answers from 190 to 210 seems to be the correct answer.

I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here and how I could optimize this. Could the problem lie in `BigInteger.isProbablePrime()`?

I'm not sure if Stackoverflow is the best place to ask this, but I seem to be stuck. I've included my code and the generated data.

I'd really appreciate it if someone would give me some hints or pointers.

**Edit:** I've run the program again simply with using the first 500,000 prime numbers; took a day to run but produced the correct answer.

Comment: You know, I was just thinking the other day that it's been weeks since we've seen an Euler question. And now, one pops up. Spooky... And if it's an exact duplicate of "that question", why did you post it again? Are you just looking for a fight? :-)

Comment: Not exactly. The other one is months old and seems to have a different intent.

Comment: Then you were very foolish saying it was an exact duplicate. I suggest you change that.

Comment: isProbablePrime - as its name suggest - isn't certain. You should something else, like generate the first n primes with the Sieve of Erastosthenes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes and then check a number with them

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm a Project Euler administrator. Please do not post information that can spoil the problem for others, particularly code and answers, even half-functioning code. Please edit your question accordingly. EDIT: Thank you for doing so!

It's not unusual for solvers to use the web to search for information on solving a problem, and it would take away some fun if they stumbled upon such a spoiler. (Yes, I know there are sites with lots of solutions ready-made, but at least they're generally for the lowered numbered easy problems.)

We have [forums](http://forum.projecteuler.net/) for discussing difficulties with problems and getting hints, which are aggressively edited for spoilers.

Comment: BS: If one does not want to have answers spoiled, he can avoid the page. QED.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you supposed to think of a clever solution which doesn't take a day or even an hour to run? :D
I think the problem is isProbablePrime, which doesn't guarantee that a number is a prime. It just says that a prime which was found could be a prime with a certain probability.
You should use an algorithm which is certain that it has found a prime.

Comment: The point of isProbablyPrime is that it is significantly faster than a more certain algorithm; plus the level of accuracy can be tuned high enough that a brute force calculation is more likely to have an error (due to hardware failure).  That is not the source of slowness.

Comment: I didn't mean that this is the source of the slowness. I meant that the problem why it didn't work the first time and then worked on a rerun could be that he is using isProbablePrime

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is incorrect because isProbablyPrime isn't always correct (hence the Probably).  It's slow, in part, because you are using BigInteger.  All the values involved will fit in a long.  Why not use a long?

Answer (score 0):

There may be some simple refactorings you could do that would save some time.  It seems that the bulk of the time is spent in the nested for loop.  The order of magnitude is n squared.  You could reduce the complexity by not nesting loops.  Another problem is that you are finding more potential results than are required.  You only need to find 200.  The reason you are needing to find more is due to the fact that you are not finding the potential results in their numeric order.  The TreeSet does keep the results in order, but the algorithm would be faster if it were able to stop when the 200th result was found.