# Get all factors of a number (iterators showdown :)

Tags: algorithm, iterator, programming-languages

You are given all the prime factors of a number, along with their multiplicities (highest powers).
The requirment is to produce all the factors of that number.

Let me give an example:

Prime factors:

- 2 (power: 3)
- 3 (power: 1)

(meaning the number is  `2^3 * 3^1 = 24`)

The expected result is:
1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24

I'm thinking of doing this (in C#) with some chained custom iterators, one for each prime factor, that would count from 0 to the power of that prime number.

How would you implement this? Use your preferred language.

This is related to [problem #23](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=23) from [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net)

Comment: I don't know how fond the Project Euler administrators are of SO exposing solutions to their problems. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010739/help-with-project-euler-200-closed .

Comment: In this case I think it is ok, because the question asks for a standard algorithm, not for the solution of the problem. Also, the problem is still rather easy, and this is not the best approach.

Comment: +1, this is not the Project Euler problem at all. This question is a very general one, and certainly a "real" programming question. (Referring to the two votes for closing it as "not a real question".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider all possible combinations of powers. For each combination, raise the primes to their corresponding power, and multiply the result.

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from itertools import product, starmap
>>> from operator import mul 
>>> 
>>> def factors(prime_factors):
...     primes, powers = zip(*prime_factors)
...     power_combos = product(*(range(p + 1) for p in powers))
...     prime_combos = (zip(primes, c) for c in power_combos)
...     return (reduce(mul, starmap(pow, c)) for c in prime_combos)
... 
>>> sorted(factors([(2, 3), (3, 1)]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 24]
```

This code uses Python 3.0. Aside from the call to [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#sorted), it makes use of iterators exclusively.

*Side remark*: too bad this question seems to be rather unpopular. I would like to see e.g. some functional solutions being posted. (I may attempt to write a Haskell solution later.)

Answer (score 6):

[Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/).

```
cartesianWith f xs = concatMap $ \y -> map (`f` y) xs
factorsOfPrimeFactorization =
    foldl (cartesianWith (*)) [1] . map (\(p, e) -> map (p^) [0..e])
```

```
> factorsOfPrimeFactorization [(2, 3), (3, 1)]
[1,2,4,8,3,6,12,24]
```

To sort the result,

```
import Data.List
cartesianWith f xs = concatMap $ \y -> map (`f` y) xs
factorsOfPrimeFactorization =
    sort . foldl (cartesianWith (*)) [1] . map (\(p, e) -> map (p^) [0..e])
```

---

[Perl](http://www.perl.org/).

```
sub factors {
    my %factorization = @_;
    my @results = (1);
    while (my ($p, $e) = each %factorization) {
        @results = map {my $i = $_; map $i*$_, @results} map $p**$_, 0..$e;
    }
    sort {$a <=> $b} @results;
}

print join($,, factors(2, 3, 3, 1)), $/;  # => 1 2 3 4 6 8 12 24
```

---

[J](http://www.jsoftware.com).

```
   /:~~.,*/"1/{:@({.^i.@{:@>:)"1 ] 2 3 ,: 3 1
1 2 3 4 6 8 12 24
```

---

These all implement the same algorithm, which is to generate the list *p*<sup>0</sup>,*p*<sup>1</sup>,…,*p*<sup>*e*</sup> for each pair (*p*,*e*) in the factorization, and take the product of each set in the Cartesian product across all those lists.

Comment: I should note that none of these languages really have a concept of "iterators"... (well, you can make tied arrays in Perl, but that's a pain).  However, due to Haskell's laziness, normal lists are like iterators in other languages, but much easier to use.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not care about the single divisors, but about the sum of all divisors of n you might want to have a look at the [Divisor Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function):

Thus the sum of the divisors of

[image: n=p_1^{a_1}\cdot p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_k^{a_k}]

is

[image: \frac{p_1^{a_1+1}-1}{p_1-1}\cdot\cdot\cdot\frac{p_k^{a_k+1}-1}{p_k-1}]

Comment: This answer relates more to the actual PE problem than to my question; however, this is a great insight! +1
Like the texify.com tip as well - is this yours?

Answer (score 0):

I first shoot without an IDE at hand so there might be some errors in there.

```
struct PrimePower
{
    public PrimePower(Int32 prime, Int32 power) : this()
    {
        this.Prime = prime;
        this.Power = power;
    }

    public Int32 Prime { get; private set; }
    public Int32 Power { get; private set; }
}
```

And then just this recursive function.

```
public IEnumerable<Int32> GetFactors(IList<PrimePowers> primePowers, Int32 index)
{
    if (index < primePowers.Length() - 1)
    {
        Int32 factor = 1;
        for (Int32 p = 0; p <= primePowers[index].Power; p++)
        {
            yield return factor * GetFactors(primePowers, index + 1);
            factor *= primePowers[index].Prime;
        }
    }
    else if (index = primePowers.Length() - 1)
    {
        Int32 factor = 1;
        for (Int32 p = 0; p <= primePowers[index].Power; p++)
        {
            yield return factor * GetFactors(primePowers, index + 1);
            factor *= primePowers[index].Prime;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
    }
}
```

It could also be an extension method and `IList<PrimerPower>` could probably weakened to `IEnumerable<PrimePower>` with a few `Skip()` and `Take()` calls. I don't like passing the index around, too, but the alternative would be copying the prime power list for each call. In consequence I think a iterative solution would be preferable - going to add one if I have an IDE again.

Answer (score -1):

Very easy to do. In fact, I wrote an article on my blog about this very thing. Check out this code.

```
#Application lists all factors/divisors for a number.
targetNumber=input('What number do you want the factors for?\n> ')
factors=[]
for i in range(1,targetNumber):
    if targetNumber%i==0:
        factors.append(i)
    elif targetNumber/i==1:
        factors.append(targetNumber)
        break
print factors
```

[Read more](http://pyfon.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/list-factors-of-number-in-python.html)